# (discord.py) How can I make my bot randomly reply to DMs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

For example, when someone DMs my bot, it says "hello" or "why are you trying to DM a bot..?"
I tried this with this code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    if message.guild is None and not message.author.bot:
        with open('dmresponses.txt') as input_file:
            long_list = [line.strip() for line in input_file]
        await message.author.send(random.choice(long_list))
```

and it worked. But, my commands like "m!help" and "m!about" stopped working. What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an `on_message` event, you need to process the commands:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message): # no need to define the type
    await client.process_commands(message)
    # rest of the code here
```

---

**References:**

- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) - "Without this coroutine, none of the commands will be triggered. If you choose to override the `on_message()` event, then you should invoke this coroutine as well."
- [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message)